# select all the rows from database's table with code igniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm new here. I have a problem in a php code with the code igniter framework.

I don't know how to use the framework and also I didn't do the code. but my boss gave me the job and I have to do.

The question is to print on screen all rows from a table (in mysql). How to do? Ask me what part of code you need.

I can paste all the code but it's very long :)

Thank you in advice!

EDIT: my problem is this: i need to create a new group of users that have only the permission to see some tables. I can create the new group and the new user of the group but i have to modify the code to let view all the info like an admin but without modify.

I can't put the code because is very long and it's formatted very bad.

Comment: You provably need to learn first, what you do. Answering this problem might lead you to another bigger problem.

Comment: Good, so the boss could give me a kick in the ass :D

I know I don't know all that, but I haven't time to do, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Past it into your model and use

```
function getAllRecords() {
    $query = $this->db->get('your table name');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Tell me if there is any issue.

Comment: thank you for the response.
Anyway, i've done a mistake not saying why I need that all.

I edit the first post.

Comment: i could not understand your requirement. Kindly, explain it.

Comment: Basically, i kind of users could read all the data but only read, not to modify. Like an admin without the write/edit permission.